# not able to convert String date to unix timestamp in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I tried to execute the below query:

```
SELECT
    L_RETURNFLAG,
    L_LINESTATUS,
    SUM(L_QUANTITY) AS SUM_QTY,
    SUM(L_EXTENDEDPRICE) AS SUM_BASE_PRICE,
    SUM(L_EXTENDEDPRICE * (1 - L_DISCOUNT)) AS SUM_DISC_PRICE,
    SUM(L_EXTENDEDPRICE * (1 - L_DISCOUNT) * (1 + L_TAX)) AS SUM_CHARGE,
    AVG(L_QUANTITY) AS AVG_QTY,
    AVG(L_EXTENDEDPRICE) AS AVG_PRICE,
    AVG(L_DISCOUNT) AS AVG_DISC,
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT_ORDER
FROM
    LINEITEM
WHERE
    unix_timestamp(L_SHIPDATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')>1000
GROUP BY
    L_RETURNFLAG,
    L_LINESTATUS
ORDER BY
    L_RETURNFLAG,
    L_LINESTATUS;
```

But,

I am getting the error:

```
 The function 'unix_timestamp' with the given argument types cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

try to cast the argument to string inside unix_timestamp